# DO IF, ELSE: Else not being computed

Tags: if-statement, spss

Only the initial if statement variable computation is being completed--the ELSE part is being ignored.  Can someone explain why?  Many thanks.

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
DO IF ((A1_SCN2_PR1_UE = 0 & A1_SCN3_PR1_UE = 0 & A1_SCN4_PR1_UE = 0 & A1_SCN5_PR1_UE = 0) | 
       (A2_SCN2_PR1_UE = 0 & A2_SCN3_PR1_UE = 0 & A2_SCN4_PR1_UE = 0 & A2_SCN5_PR1_UE = 0) | 
       (A3_SCN2_PR1_UE = 0 & A3_SCN3_PR1_UE = 0 & A3_SCN4_PR1_UE = 0 & A3_SCN5_PR1_UE = 0)).
Compute FM_zero = 1.
ELSE.
Compute FM_zero = 0.
End IF.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Code looks fine. It's probably either your data/variables or the logic operation which is erroneous.

Comment: Are all your variables defined? This article from IBM: [DO IF, ELSE with COMPUTE leaving some variable values missing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476060) explains the case of 'omitting' `Compute` calculations when some variables are undefined in boolean expression in DO IF.

Comment: I know they are because I selected them from SPSS point, click, add menu.

Solution I've found is to set FM_zero = 0 initially.

It seems that in creating the variable and setting the non-1 values to missing, it won't then accept "ELSE" to change them--ie, it seems that ELSE  COMPUTE FM_zero = O. would need to be ...Sysmis(FM_zero) = 0.

Any idea why??

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your ELSE is not being computed, but I suggest you drop the DO IF and go this way instead:

```
compute FM_zero = 
    ((A1_SCN2_PR1_UE = 0 & A1_SCN3_PR1_UE = 0 & A1_SCN4_PR1_UE = 0 & A1_SCN5_PR1_UE = 0) | 
    (A2_SCN2_PR1_UE = 0 & A2_SCN3_PR1_UE = 0 & A2_SCN4_PR1_UE = 0 & A2_SCN5_PR1_UE = 0) | 
    (A3_SCN2_PR1_UE = 0 & A3_SCN3_PR1_UE = 0 & A3_SCN4_PR1_UE = 0 & A3_SCN5_PR1_UE = 0)).
```

This will put a 1 in all true cases and 0 in all false cases.

Answer (score 1):

SPSS uses three-valued logic: True, False, or don't know (sysmis).
From the Syntax Reference Manual...
Missing values returned by the logical expression on DO IF or on any ELSE IF cause control to pass to
the END IF command at that point.

So generally you should put the sysmis test first in your DO IF and follow with appropriate ELSE IF/ELSE.